# C# Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms not remember answers to access to geolocation

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, webview2

After loading the page (with the openstreet map), WebView2 asks for geolocation permission every time it is started (I do not clear WebView2 cookies - but I don't set anything either for cookies - is that wrong?).

How to set C# `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms` (`webView2.CoreWebView2`? ) to remember a one-time user answer or set permission to access geolocation by default, as for example in the Edge browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the experimental [`SetPermissionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2profile.setpermissionstateasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1671-prerelease#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2profile-setpermissionstateasync(microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2permissionkind-system-string-microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2permissionstate)) API on the profile to accomplish this - it's part of the **1.0.1671-prerelease** package and should be in the next release package.

You can also handle the [`PermissionRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.permissionrequested?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1671-prerelease) event to intercept permission requests and set permission state from the [event `args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2permissionrequestedeventargs.state?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1671-prerelease#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2permissionrequestedeventargs-state).